# Having troubles loading a GIF image in my application

Tags: android, gif, picasso, android-glide, animated-gif

so i was trying to load a GIF image using a link into my application, but i couldn't find how.

i tried using Glide and Picasso but i still couldn't resolve my problem, at first i thought i might have something in my app that's stopping the GIF from loading so i tried creating a new app just to test loading a GIF in an app and still couldn't load a single GIF.

I have looked around for a question like mine and tested some of the answers given but none of them worked!

so if anyone can show me a way to load a GIF in an app i would be quite thankful, and i can share the code for my app but as i stated earlier i am trying a new empty app and has no actual code in it.

Comment: No actual code? You will have added some code where you try to load the gif. In your app? Or in an ImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's too little information to know what happened. It would be better to show more detail about the code you tried and the result.

However, This is a [Simple Example](https://github.com/rKaiProgramer/GIFWithGlideExample)

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

add internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**build.gradle(:app)**:

add Glide Library.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
```

**activity_main.xml**:

add an ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**MainActivity.kt:**

load GIF into imageView

```
 val url = "https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7527pa7qs9kCG78A/giphy.gif"
 Glide.with(this)
     .load(url)
     .into(imageView)
```

Comment: I just created a new app and literally copied exactly what you wrote here (just added some semicolons cause am using java) and it still fails to load the GIF. i tried checking the log and i found this : W/Glide: Load failed for https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7527pa7qs9kCG78A/giphy.gif with size [1080x2038]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource

Comment: Are there more logs below the `Failed to load resource`? 
Like this: `There was 1 root cause: com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)     
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 1): class`

Comment: ok so for some reasons now it is working, but when i tried to implement it in my real app i get this message in the logcat  :  com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)

Comment: + I think the problem might be related to the message shown in the Logcat :Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to d205bpvrqc9yn1.cloudfront.net not permitted

Comment: so i have fixed my problem, i had to add this in my manifest file under the application tag : 
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: Good work! You found out more info and solved the problem by yourself.

Comment: thanks, although your help have saved me a lot of time an researching, so thanks for the help, again.